# Symfony2 Include in html in Twig

Tags: html, symfony, twig

I am developing an application using Symfony2 and twig for templates. I am using a 3 level structure for templates. Base.html.twig, layout.html.twig and childtemplate.html.twig.
The problem is I am trying to include one example.html (common html file) in the next child template by using include but it doesnt work properly. Where can the problem be?

```
{# src/Anotatzailea/AnotatzaileaBundle/Resources/views/Page/testuaanotatu.html.twig #}
{% extends 'AnotatzaileaAnotatzaileaBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Testua anotatu{% endblock%}

{% block body %}
    {% include "var/www/Symfony/web/example.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Depends on where it's located. Let's say it's in `Anotatzailea/AnotatzaileaBundle/Resources/views/example.html.twig`; then you would include it like this:

```
{% include 'AnotatzaileaAnotatzaileaBundle::example.html.twig' %}
```

Comment: Just for reference, if the template is in `Anotatzailea/AnotatzaileaBundle/Resources/views/subfolder/example.html.twig`, then the include statement must be: `{% include 'AnotatzaileaAnotatzaileaBundle:subfolder:example.html.twig' %}`

Comment: Just for reference if you multi level subdirectories like Anotatzailea/AnotatzaileaBundle/Resources/views/subfolder/subfolder1/example.html.twig then include them like {% include 'AnotatzaileaAnotatzaileaBundle:subfolder:subfolder1/example.html.twig' %}